# openGL Alpha Blending for full Opacity or Transparency

Tags: opengl, alpha, opengl-3, alphablending

**ORIGINAL:**

I asked about this subject before, but my initial example was a bit incomplete, and I think I can be more specific about my problem now.

For context, I am using openGL 3.3 on an old Apple mac computer and am trying to render overlapping layers of quads. Each quad is uv mapped to a piece of a png 4096 x 4096 texture that has areas of full transparency.

I want to use alpha blending so the transparent sections of layer N reveal the opaque parts of layer N - 1 (behind it). 
Because I don't need semi-transparency, I'd like to know-- is there a way to configure `glBlendFuncSeparate` so the fragment color is just the front-most opaque texel--no additional multiplication required?

I tried something like this:

`glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);`

but I think I completely misunderstand the meaning of the parameters. I thought they meant: keep the source color and set it as the destination color... apply the original alpha. (I know this is absolutely wrong).

Initially I thought this was an xyz question and searched for other reasons that I am noticing performance issues, but even though the above function call results in completely wrong colors, it causes my animations to run smooth even in the hello-triangle + sin(time) translation case.

I would post some of my code, but it consists mostly of setting up vertex buffers and large static array declarations for testing. My shaders are basically pass-through: (e.g. the main function in my fragment shader:)

```
void main(void)
{
    vec4 texel = texture(tex0, v_uv);

    color = vec4(texel.rgb, texel.a);
}
```

and the textures load correctly. I have set-up rendering from back to front.

How would I set-up this sort of rendering?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I tried:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND); 
glBlendFuncSeparate(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO, GL_ONE, GL_ONE);
glBlendEquationSeparate(GL_FUNC_ADD, GL_MAX);
```

but only the front layer with opaque white for its transparency appears. I checked the RGBA values and it looks like the transparent sections are [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0] so it looks like I need to ignore the color when alpha is 0.0, even if the color is not [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, a]. To simulate this, I added an `if (alpha is 0.0), then discard;` statement, but then the lag returns.

So the functions are not totally correct, or something else is wrong.

For more information about my setup:

(I posted my large texture at the bottom)

The vertex and index data for each layer would be too long to post, but there are three quads per each of the five layers (I pass the camera position to the shader and use the z position value for offsets). This may be a separate source of inefficiency.

The full fragment and vertex shaders:

// vertex

```
#version 330 core
precision highp float;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 a_uv;

out vec2 v_uv;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;
uniform float u_aspect;
uniform vec3 u_position_cam;

uniform int u_count_layers;

void main(void) 
{
    // scroll speed depends on the inverse of the z position
    float speed_factor = (1.0 / pow(2.0, u_count_layers - a_position.z));

    // x offset
    float X = -u_position_cam.x * speed_factor;

    // make sure the bg quad jumps back to the correct position
    X = mod(X, (u_aspect) * 2.0);
    X += a_position.x;

    // y offset 
    float Y = -clamp(u_position_cam.y, 0.0, 2.0) * speed_factor;
    Y += a_position.y;

    gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(X, Y, a_position.z, 1.0);

    v_uv = a_uv;
}
```

// fragment

```
#version 330 core
precision highp float;

in vec2 v_uv;

uniform sampler2D tex0;

out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 texel = texture(tex0, v_uv);

    color = vec4(texel);
}
```

[This mostly unresolved stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079366/2d-opengl-scene-slows-down-with-lots-of-overlapping-shapes) discusses the issue I'm experiencing-- in short, many overlapping transparent shapes cause lag, but if the same shapes do not overlap, then everything is fine.
Of course, the alternative blending algorithm hasn't been found yet.

Thinking about the numbers--
Each texture section covers 1280 x 720 pixels. There are 5 layers, 3 quads each.
For each pixel I'm doing the same work N layers times, so 4,608,000?
I guess that could be prohibitively expensive. I am also doing weird modulo arithmetic and offsets.
If the way I'm trying to achieve parallax scrolling is too clumsy, then how would it be done efficiently? I'm willing to change my algorithm/setup if there is definitely a better way of doing this. I am curious how textures and transparent layers would be set-up correctly to avoid the problems that I'm experiencing.

A thought: what if I rendered from front to back? How would the blend functions change? (I know that you normally render transparent objects from back to front, but here I just need to stop checking layers once I hit one with alpha == 1.0).

[image: 4096x4096 bg texture "atlas"]

Answer (score 0):

This question of yours is extremely hard to understand but it seems the key is

> the fragment color is just the front-most opaque texel--no additional
>   multiplication required

So are you saying you just want to draw those pixels that have alpha of `1.0` while the rest are discarded? Like the following example was true:

You are drawing 3 textures of size 3x1. First texture has all 3 pixels opaque; second has first 2 pixels opaque and last has only first  pixel opaque. Now the result should be that first pixel is from texture 3, second is from 2 and third is from 1.

If this being true then first let's assume your textures already output either `1.0` or `.0` for alpha value. After you clear the buffer your blend func should be `GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` for colors. What this means is that the oncoming color will be multiplied with its source alpha and mixed to current color:

- For alpha `1.0` it means that source color will be fully used (multiplied by `1.0`) and destination color completely ignored (multiplied by `0.0`) `destination = source*1.0 + destination*.0`. In common language this pixel will be completely redrawn by the new color.
- For alpha `.0` it means that source color will be completely ignored (multiplied by `.0`) and destination color fully used (multiplied by `1.0`) `destination = source*0.0 + destination*1.0`. In common language this pixel will be completely preserved as it was and the new color will be ignored.

You probably don't even need to use the alpha component of blending so I guess `GL_ZERO, GL_ONE` can be applied saying that you will keep alpha channel as it was from `glClear`. Otherwise the same rules apply to alpha channel so do what you need to.

If you need to further define "opaque" you might want to control that in shader. Some threshold may be applied like:

```
void main(void)
{
    vec4 texel = texture(tex0, v_uv);
    color = vec4(texel.rgb, step(texel.a, 0.5));
}
```

Note that even if your input texture only has `0.0` and `1.0` values this may not be the case in your shader unless you use `nearest` filter on your texture. Interpolated values may be of any magnitude.

Comment: I apologize if I was a bit unclear. I've appended details to my original question.